# Django join button to goal

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I try to create changing button after user join to Goal.

I have work buttons, but i don't know how to change this in template.

I try to do this with boolean field, when user click "Join", boolean field change to True, and then in template I try:

```
{% if goal.joined %}
<Delete join>
{% else %}
<join to goal>
{% endif %}
```

Models:

```
class Goal(models.Model, Activity):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='goals', verbose_name='Tło')
    body = HTMLField(verbose_name='Treść')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cele'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('goaldetail', args=[str(self.slug)])

    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.author

    def add_user_to_list_of_attendees(self, user):
        registration = Joined.objects.create(user = user,
                                                    goal = self,
                                                    created_at = timezone.now())

    def remove_user_from_list_of_attendees(self, user):
        registration = Joined.objects.get(user = user, goal = self)
        registration.delete()

class Joined(models.Model, Activity):
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='joined')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='joined_users')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    joined = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is None and self.created_at is None:
            self.created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.joined = True
        super(Joined, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.user
```

Views:

```
def joined_add(request, pk):
    this_goal = Goal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    this_goal.add_user_to_list_of_attendees(user=request.user)
    return redirect('goaldetail', slug=this_goal.slug)

def joined_delete(request, pk):
    this_goal = Goal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    this_goal.remove_user_from_list_of_attendees(request.user)
    return redirect('goaldetail', slug=this_goal.slug)

def goaldetail(request, slug):
    goal = get_object_or_404(Goal, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'goals/detail.html',
                {'goal': goal})
```

Path:

```
path('joined/<int:pk>', views.joined_add, name='joined_add'),
path('joined-delete/<int:pk>', views.joined_delete, name='joined_delete'),
```

Create and delete works perfect, but on template this button don't change. I try in many ways and don't know how to do this.

Comment: a `goal` object can have many users that join, so I assume you want to check if the goal has been joined by the current user in the template. `{% goal.joined %}` is just a reference to the `RelatedObjectManager` , `{% goal.joined.all %}` returns all the `Joined` instances with this goal. You should probably add a context variable to your "goaldetail" view to set a boolean flag whether the current `request.user` has joined this `goal` or not.

Comment: This makes sens! It's possible to give me a example view?

Comment: I don’t know how your “goaldetail” view looks like. Look up in the Django documentation how context variables are used to render a template.

Comment: I add goal detail view. Before i write this question i search through documentation and many apps similar to this and stil don't have answer.

Comment: Just create a variable `joined` that checks if the current user has joined the goal and add it to the context.